# Remove text from a p tag and add a class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm triying to accomplish is that everything there's a p tag with word "border" on it it will remove the text inside it (the word border) and add a class to the P. So far this works for finding the p and adding the class. How can I remove the text?

```
$('#main-body-content').find('p').filter(':contains(border)').addClass("border");
```

Comment: does the `<p>` tag have only text, or other elements as well?

Comment: You can get rid of `.find` and `.filter` with this selector: `'#main-body-content p:contains(border)'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this......

```
$('#main-body-content').find('p').filter(':contains(border)').text("").addClass("border");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/egjfW/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// find all divs that have attribute class
$('p').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('class'); }).each(function() {
    $(this).html('');
});
```